# Improving Teradata offloading performance using Apache Spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I am having more than 1 TB data in Teradata ,I have to import and process the data in spark code ,I have done all efficient ways in spark submit executor memory,core count and driver memory,core even though It's taking more time in the cluster environment.My cluster data node size is 4 node and more than 500 gb what are all other main consideration are there to improve performance..please help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sales.registerTempTable("FINAL_RESULT")

 val Sales_data = spark.sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * from FINAL_RESULT DISTRIBUTE BY VALITITY_DATE""")

Sales_data.write.partitionBy("VALITITY_DATE").saveAsTable("test.Aggregate_Data")

Sales_data.write.parquet("hdfs:///tmp/ENTERPRAISE/SITE_DATA")                                     This my code I am getting the data from Terradata while trying to do 1 TB Sales_data it's processing more time it's not responding?what is the best way to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

If you post your code for loading the DataFrame I may be able to help more. In situations like this I usually find the Spark connector is doing something unexpected during the load. If you have a way to inspect the queries that Spark is running on the Teradata cluster you might find that it's loading in an inefficient order.

What are you doing with the data after it's loaded? Is there a reason you need 100% of your dataset in memory in your Spark cluster? Teradata stores data on disk in a more compressed format than it will be in memory on your Spark cluster. You may have more success doing predicate pushdown to limit the amount of data you're pulling into Spark. See [Push down a query to the database engine](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine) and the following "Push down optimization" for more.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin...I am getting data from 5 table and doing sum operation and aggregate function and finally i am doing the below operation Sales.registerTempTable("FINAL_RESULT") val Sales_data = spark.sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * from FINAL_RESULT DISTRIBUTE BY VALITITY_DATE""") Sales_data.write.partitionBy("VALITITY_DATE").saveAsTable("test.Aggregate_Data") Sales_data.write.parquet("hdfs:///tmp/ENTERPRAISE/SITE_DATA") This my code I am getting the data from Terradata while trying to do 1 TB Sales_data it's processing more time it's not responding?what is the best way to improve performance

Comment: Loss Reason:Container killed by Yarn for exceeding memory limit.22.1 GB of 22GB physical memory used.consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryoverhead 1)This is the exception I am getting while try to run the above code 2)I am giving executor memory size is 24 gb my cluster is having 4 node and more than 500 gb size